# iOS notifications in Qt

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I am trying to incorporate native notifications in my iOS application written in Qt + QML. For the desktop world I am simply using `QSystemTrayIcon` (works in Windows, macOS and Linux), for Android I am using a custom Java class called via `QAndroidJniObject`.

I don't know how to accomplish this for the iOS- is there a way to do this in C++ only?